Hyper-V guest network adapter disappears after restart
The Hyper-V network adapter inside a VM disappears after restart. It does not appear in Device Manager and networking doesn't work.
If I add a new network adapter in the VM settings it shows up live and works until reboot, then disappears again.
How can I make the adapter persist after restart?
Environment

Host: Windows 11 22H2
Guest: Windows Server 2019 (10.0.17763.5458, February 2024)
Guest was working for years without issue, this suddenly started with no obvious changes.

I've tried

Remove the adapter in the VM settings and add again; causes the device to show up in Device Manager, and networking works, but after restart the device disappears again.
Use a different virtual switch (including none) for the adapter.
Change VM settings for the network adapter (static/dynamic MAC, hardware acceleration, and so on) makes no difference.


Never seen anything like this in years of using various versions of Hyper-V. Looks like a bug to me.

This isn't a proper solution, but I found a work-around:
The disappearing network adapter is always the first adapter. If you add two adapters to your VM with the first not connected to any Hyper-V switch and the second being the "real" adapter then after rebooting, the VM no longer sees the first dummy adapter but the 2nd adapter remains in Device Manager and networking works.
